# Is it a must that I torque down passenger side motor mount on 09 Ford Focus SE sedan?

Tags: ford, focus, motor-mounts, torque-specification

What potential problems could occur if I tightened the passenger side motor mount by hand and didn't use a torque wrench? 09 Ford Focus SE sedan

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but does "by hand" mean with a hand tool like a ratchet or literally by hand?

Answer (score 1):

None really as long as you have it sufficiently tight - if too loose it will vibrate looser and cause damage.

Many bolts do have a torque specified but they just get tightened - lug or wheel nuts are correctly tightened to the torque specified in most cases now. Any shop that uses a buzz gun I would avoid...

The drives shaft nut usually gets tightened to FT - as many places don’t have a torque wrench sufficiently large...